# Issue in Conditional hiding in cognos report ver 10

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-bi

I already have a conditional block which controls 10 charts like chart 1 .....chart 10 based on block variable called '`Chart`' now I have to conditionally hide chart 3 , bcoz the design of chart 3 differs based on prompt `value = complex`.

So I tried using style variable and render variables to hide chart 3, I noticed the conditions works only if click on the submit button second time. during the first run its not rendering properly.

```
case when paramvalue='complex'
then 'Y'
else 'N'
end
```

If I try to pull the data item from query it throws error as its not referenced in the layout.

I tried many combinations but not working. Quick help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> it throws error as its not referenced in the layout.

*Normally* you use the 'properties' property of the rendering object (i.e. list, singleton) to define query items that aren't in your list but need to be referenced.

This works for lists but generally does not work for charts or crosstabs. If you can somehow squeeze your query item on to the chart then this error will go away.